# Filling R matrix using 1 column of data

Tags: r, matrix

Let's say I have a vector

```
x <- c(1:30)
```

What I want to do is create a matrix of say nrow=30 & ncol=3 and end up with the a matrix using the vector that begins on row 3 with (1,2,3), row 4 = (2, 3, 4), row 5 = (3, 4, 5) and so on until I end up on row 30 with (28, 29, 30).

Both row 1 & 2 have no values

I've looked around but cant seem to find this particular example.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Some answers below.  I was looking for a pure matrix statement that could do it all in one shot.  Josilber does that using rbind & cbind below.  Just thought I had seen a very craft "matrix" statement that accomplished the same thing very quickly.  But rbind & cbind are very fast as well so i'll be trying that.  That said, if you know of a good matrix 1-liner, I'm all ears.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another approach:

```
make_mat <- function(x, nrow, ncol)
{
  seqx <- seq_along(x)
  do.call(rbind,
          c(as.list(rep(NA, (ncol - 1))),
          list(t(mapply(function(i, j) x[i:j], 
                 head(seqx, -(ncol - 1)), 
                 head(seqx, -(ncol - 1)) + (ncol - 1))))))
}

make_mat(1:5, 5, 3)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]   NA   NA   NA
#[3,]    1    2    3
#[4,]    2    3    4
#[5,]    3    4    5
set.seed(101); x = runif(5)
x
#[1] 0.37219838 0.04382482 0.70968402 0.65769040 0.24985572
make_mat(x, 5, 3)
#           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
#[1,]         NA         NA        NA
#[2,]         NA         NA        NA
#[3,] 0.37219838 0.04382482 0.7096840
#[4,] 0.04382482 0.70968402 0.6576904
#[5,] 0.70968402 0.65769040 0.2498557
```

Comment: me likey.  I'm looking for speed so I'll compare this to the rbind/cbind one.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Just tested this and the others.  This one is the fastest.

system.time(m1 <- F_make_mat(1:lenx, lenx, lookback))
  user  system elapsed 
   0.05    0.00    0.05 

> dim(m1)
[1] 5677   61

Thanks again!! Have a great weekend!

Comment: This works very well with sequential data.  If I had a time series of continuous data that I wanted to lay the same way, what would you do differently here?  And by "same" I mean with the "lag" and then ordered across the matrix row in sequence of the time series.  TY!

Comment: @user3293430 : I'm not sure, but maybe the edit is what you mean?

Comment: @user3293430 I'm not sure if you've encountered the `microbenchmark` function in the `microbenchmark` package, but it does a better job than `system.time` of timing fast-executing code.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the little known `embed` function:

```
rbind(NA,NA, embed( 1:30,  3)[,3:1] )
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA   NA
 [3,]    1    2    3
 [4,]    2    3    4
 [5,]    3    4    5
 [6,]    4    5    6
 [7,]    5    6    7
 [8,]    6    7    8

snipped....
[27,]   25   26   27
[28,]   26   27   28
[29,]   27   28   29
[30,]   28   29   30
```

Comment: the solution added by alexis_laz is the fastest and gets right to exactly what I wanted.  Thank you though for the answer. I'm new and don't have enough S.O. cred to vote yet. Sorry

Comment: Huh? Thought you wanted a "pure matrix statement".

Comment: This works well too but if ncol= 61, I would have to add 61 "NA"s in this execution unless I'm missing an easy way to rbind 61 "NA"s in one statement as well.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- sapply(1:3, function(i) c(rep(NA, 3-i), x, rep(NA, i)))
x[1,] <- x[2,] <- NA
x <- x[1:30,]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one line with `rbind` and `cbind`:

```
rbind(NA, NA, cbind(x[1:(length(x)-2)], x[2:(length(x)-1)], x[c(-1, -2)]))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]   NA   NA   NA
#  [2,]   NA   NA   NA
#  [3,]    1    2    3
#  [4,]    2    3    4
#  [5,]    3    4    5
#  [6,]    4    5    6
#  [7,]    5    6    7
#  [8,]    6    7    8
#  [9,]    7    8    9
# [10,]    8    9   10
# [11,]    9   10   11
# [12,]   10   11   12
# [13,]   11   12   13
# [14,]   12   13   14
# [15,]   13   14   15
# [16,]   14   15   16
# [17,]   15   16   17
# [18,]   16   17   18
# [19,]   17   18   19
# [20,]   18   19   20
# [21,]   19   20   21
# [22,]   20   21   22
# [23,]   21   22   23
# [24,]   22   23   24
# [25,]   23   24   25
# [26,]   24   25   26
# [27,]   25   26   27
# [28,]   26   27   28
# [29,]   27   28   29
# [30,]   28   29   30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- matrix(NA,nrow=30,ncol=3)
for(i in 1:ncol(a)) a[3:30,i]<- (1:30)[i:(i+28-1)]
a
```

Comment: This is how I started but want a more efficient way to fill the matrix than using a for loop. But thanks!